# i have two text box in two different pages a

Tags: jsf

i have two text box in two different pages and same variable use in two text box when enter value in first text box it's reflection show in second text box , how i reduce it in jsf ?

Comment: Please update your question.  Its not clear!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `@SessionScoped` bean named `GeneralBean`

Set a variable there e.g.:

```
private String name;
```

add `getters` and `setters`.

In the pages where the user enters his data you should have

```
<h:form>
<h:inputText value="#{generalBean.getName}">
<f:ajax event="change" />
</h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

Using Ajax, whenever he changes the value it will affect the `name` variable which appears also in the other screen.

**EDITED**:

I presumed that you are using JSF2.0. If not, please indicate it.

**EDITED**:

Since you are using JSF1.1 you will need external tool support.

You can use RichFaces `a4j:support`.

For that you need to download [richfaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces).

Use a4j:support. See an example here:
[a4j:support](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html)

**EDITED**:

This answer is if the pages are not opened simultaneously.If they are opened at the same time you will have to use [richfaces push option](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/push.jsf?c=push)in the other one.

Comment: thanx but i facing same problem

Comment: a4j:support. using in UI but problem is same

Comment: @Odelya:  Have you noticed this in his question "two text box in two different pages"?  Your answer stays good if the 2 inputtext is in same page

Comment: if u don't mind give me ur emailid for asking question related jsf

Comment: @vivek: I prefer if you do it through the site so others could enjoy it:)